# How to get an anonymous block

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks

From within an observer, I can use

```
 Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->getBlock('some_block')
```

to get a block for manipulation.

This method uses the block's name as a reference to identify and retrieve it from the layout. In most cases this is OK, but if `Mage_Core_Model_Layout`'s `createBlock` method is called without a name, which it is in some core code, the block is given the name `ANONYMOUS_n`, where `n` is the number of blocks in the layout object.

Is there any way I can retrieve the anonymous block within my observer?

Comment: If it's a block of a specific type you could potentially use the block type I reckon

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism The get block method Mage_Core_Model_Layout takes a block name as an argument. There is also a getAllBlocks method, so maybe I could use that and filter on the block type.

Comment: yeah I was referring to the `getAllBlocks` method.

Comment: which is the event that you are observing ? Answer is fully depend on that !!!

Comment: @RajeevKTomy actually I'd be interested in an answer which is independent of the event being observed!!! I happen to be observing the resource_get_tablename event. I understand that if I were observing core_layout_block_create_after, then the block would be passed within the observer argument.

Answer (score 1):

Not without more information about the block. This could be a combination of parent block and block type (via `getChildren()` of the parent), or  from where it was created (you could observe `core_layout_block_create_after` to monitor creation of anonymous blocks)